# Show content from one domain on another with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to mask the url of one domain in favor of other domain. To be specific... visitor types http://www.whatever.com/admin into his browser and instead of this, the content from http://www.better.com/admin is shown, but visitor still sees whatever.com domain. This should work even with subpages, http://www.better.com/admin/absolutelyeverything is actually http://www.whatever.com/admin/absolutelyeverything, but still, visitor sees the first url.

Is something like this possible with .htaccess please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Hi, yes I think so. Don't you have any link which deals with such rewriting please? I was searching for a while but I didn't find anything for my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use of [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) ([mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)) with the `P` flag will allow this.

Comment: Hi, yes I think so. Don't you have any link which deals with such rewriting please? I was searching for a while but I didn't find anything for my problem. Thanks

Comment: @Machi: Did you take a chance to look at the links I gave?

Comment: Yes, but I don't get most of that stuff, I'm really lame in this .htaccess stuff :(

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to rewriting:

If both locations are on the same server, and the server runs a unix-like OS, a symlink might work (though I'm not sure whether apache needs to be configured specially to follow them).

Suppose you have www.whatever.com mapped to `/var/www/whatever`, and www.better.com mapped to `/var/www/better`, then you could put the admin directory at `/var/www/whatever/admin`, and symlink `/var/www/better/admin` there, e.g. `ln --symbolic /var/www/whatever/admin /var/www/better/admin`. Or you could put the admin directory on its own path, and symlink there from both websites.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid we can't configure these things on our hosting :(.

Comment: You mean your web hosting doesn't allow you to create symlinks?